# Can a 2-column grid of info be acceptable if it mitigates an awkwardly large amount of white space?

Tags: forms, layout, white-space, multi-column, column

[image]

I'm in the middle of a psuedo-overhaul of my company's platform, with an emphasis on "object-level" pages (ie the page for an individual task, or individual appointment).

A problem I'm running into is that the info for many of these pages is laid out in a two-column format (see pic), which I know any competent ux designer will tell you is bad for scanning. But while combining both columns into one single left-aligned column might improve scannability, it would also leave just a gaping void of whitespace on the right portion of the page. I can't really articulate any ux code this violates beyond just looking ridiculous and stark, but it still seems like an issue worth surfacing.

Any thoughts on this? I want to follow best practices but I also would like to preserve a sense of visual balance and appeal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is whether your users are currently blind to that second column or not. Maybe it has been there for a long time and has become a learned behavior to check. Try to get some data on this first.

It seems like the second column wouldn't necessarily violate the F pattern since it's well within the top of the page / top of the F. Furthermore, there are [other scanning patterns that emerge from different scenarios](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/text-scanning-patterns-eyetracking/). For example, a user seeking medical appointment information may be more motivated than someone scanning news and therefore altering their scanning pattern.

Visual treatments can also help cope with findability. For example, if "Appointment Details" and "Note to Patient" are treated as two separate tiles, they could live side by side as two distinct tiles. This could alter the scanning behavior by letting the user scan information in each tile / chunks (typical in dashboards) rather than as a single page.

Comment: hey Nicolas thanks a lot for your thoughtful response. I guess a follow-up question I have is that if 2-column IS permissible in this circumstance, would that require the form creating this "appointment" be 2-columns as well, with the layout mapped to this page 1/1? Because currently that form is only 1 column, whereas the resulting page is 2

Comment: For forms, 1 column is best practice. Although there are cases where 2 columns perform better, it is entirely a case by case basis and needs to be tested. However, I don't see any glaring issues of going from a 1 column form to a 2 column display. Plenty of applications don't match form input to final display layout one to one.